# .gitignore with wildcards for filenames

Tags: git, gitignore, git-bash

My .gitignore file has the following entries. I am trying multiple things here as I can't seem to get my file ignored;

```
WinAppSetup/*.exe
/WinAppSetup/*.exe
WinAppSetup/setup.exe
**/WinAppSetup/setup.exe
```

When I run `git status` from git bash, I still see;

```
    modified:   WinAppSetup/setup.exe
```

What entry in my .gitignore will allow me to ignore this file?

After editing .gitignore, do I need to close and re-open git bash to have the .gitignore file re-read?

**UPDATE**

As per user2407038's comment, the issue was that the file already existed in the repository. I was able to remove the file locally, stage and then commit those changes and update my remote. A new build of the application then successfully ignored the file.

It seems I can also update my .gitignore file without having to close and re-open git bash too.

Comment: If your file is shown as modified, so it is in the repository. `.gitignore` only works on files not yet in the repository (or index). Perhaps you want to delete this file from the repo?

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't even think about that. I'll bet that is what it is. I'll try and delete it and see if that sorts things out.

Comment: @user2407038, add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I wonder what is the answer to the title..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`.gitignore` won't ignore a file that's already in your repository. You have to first remove the file for your repository.

You can remove a file from the repository *without deleting the actual file* with `git rm --cached`.

```
git rm --cached WinAppSetup/setup.exe
```

In this sort of situation I usually have the new `.gitignore` entry and the removal of the ignored file from the repository in the same commit.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, as it seems to do what I need, but the suggestion provided by @user2407038 is what really helped me fix this specific issue.