# How to add to gitignore specific files?

Tags: git, gitignore

can you please tell me how to add to .gitignore files with names that contain a part of the name.

My file 2021-11-08-11-29-42.060-VBoxSVC-8706.log

Example .gitignore

```
*VBox*.log
```

Comment: If the file(s) are already in the repository, you first have to delete them from the repository before you can ignore them. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48414480/650012) for example.

Comment: Is the file in a subdir? `*` won't match subdirs. Use `**/*VBox*.log` for that.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Oh, thank you very much, the example from the link response works.